# Broken Pagination from 2nd page onwards - PHP PDO MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, php, paging

My pagination script is displaying the same results as first page from the 2nd page onward.

Here is my original pagination script used for articles, etc. It returns the articles and categories and joins them to display the article & category for every article but only dispay the last two months' articles.

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] :1;
$perpage =10;
$start = ($page>1) ? ($page*$perpage)-$perpage :0;
$selects = $DB->prepare("
            SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS articles.*, art_categories.*
            FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
            ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
            WHERE articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
            AND articles.publishDate < DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
            ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT {$start},10
            ");
$selects->execute();
$selects= $selects->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = $DB->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total")->fetch()['total'];
$pages = ceil($total / $perpage);
```

I then used it again for my article categories page that lists all articles according to their categoryID via a dropdown menu here is the pagination code I used.

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] :1;
$perpage =10;
$start = ($page>1) ? ($page*$perpage)-$perpage :0;
$selects = $DB->prepare("
                        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
                             articles.*, 
                             art_categories.*
                        FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                        ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                        WHERE art_categories.categoryID=:cat_id 
                        ORDER BY publishDate DESC LIMIT {$start},10
                        ");

$selects->bindParam(':cat_id', $_GET['categoryID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$selects->execute();
$selects= $selects->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = $DB->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total")->fetch()['total'];
$pages = ceil($total / $perpage);
```

Here is the code I use for the pagination itself

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++):?>
      <li><a href="categories.php?categoryID=<?php echo $cate['categoryID']; ?>?page=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
    <?php endfor;?>
</ul>
```

Now I've read a bunch of articles regarding this where people suggest saving the ['page'] as part of the $_SESSION but I have had no luck trying that.

```
session_start();
$page = isset($_SESSION['page']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['page']) ? $_SESSION['page'] : 1;
$_SESSION['page'] = $page;
$perpage =10;
$start = ($page>1) ? ($page*$perpage)-$perpage :0;
$selects = $DB->prepare("
                        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
                             articles.*, 
                             art_categories.*
                        FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                        ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                        WHERE art_categories.categoryID=:cat_id 
                        ORDER BY publishDate DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET {$start}
                        ");

$selects->bindParam(':cat_id', $_GET['categoryID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$selects->execute();
$selects= $selects->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = $DB->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total")->fetch()['total']; 
$pages = ceil($total / $perpage);
```

The URL is as follows when you click on the pagination, but the content stays the same:

```
categories.php?categoryID=1?page=1
categories.php?categoryID=1?page=2
categories.php?categoryID=1?page=3
```

I have no idea how to go forward from here any assistance would be awesome and I am still learning PHP & MySQL so I am not an advanced programmer at all.

This question is closed.

Comment: Read [_my blog_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) on pagination.

Comment: Okay I found my mistake after trying everything and still not working I saw the following: categories.php?categoryID=1?page=1 but it should've read categories.php?categoryID=1&page=1. I had a ? instead of a & for the page and now its sorted.